# How to de-structure object of arrays from API and put into state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Basically I'm learning how do API calls and I'm messing around with the the open weather API, trying to display the name and and temperature of a few different cities. The problem is the response is an object of arrays and trying to put all the names of the cities into to state so I can display them. Whats the best way to get all the names into state?

[image]

[image: object]

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    const [cityName, setCityName] = useState("");
    const [temp, setTemp] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

    const fetchData = () => {
        //api variables (normily stored somewhere safer)
        const lat = "35.320696399999996";
        const lon = "-75.8232391";
        const key = "115475ac7a8dda2a7e7ec0b27b93ce35";
        const cnt = "5";
        const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&cnt=${cnt}&appid=${key}`;

        axios
            .get(url)
            .then((res) => {
                
                console.log(res.data.list);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return <div className="App"></div>;
}
export default App;
```

Comment: So from the response that is an array of objects, you want city name, temp, and a description? Can you provide an example result or what you expect to parse out of the response? Your states are all empty strings but your question implies you want an array for the cities, temps, and descriptions.

Comment: Right, so I guess in cityName state i would want ["Buxon", "Swanquarter","Dare","Wanchese","manteo"] So then I could map through them below and render them on the page. I will change the states to empty arrays but the only way I know how to set a name to it would be like setState(res.data.list[0}.name) but I don't want to have to do that for every city.

Comment: Do you want separate arrays for each, or would one single array of objects with the properties you want suffice? (*A single array would be easier to map in JSX*) What is the description? Is that from the response data?

Comment: Single array is what I would want to map for JSX. Description is also in response but its nested in the weather object, edited post to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the response list to a new array with ***just*** the properties you want. Update your component to have a single "data" state array to hold the mapped response values.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const fetchData = () => {
  
  ...

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.list);

      // destructure name, main.temp, and weather
      const data = res.data.list.map(({ name, main: { temp }, weather }) => {
        // weather is an array of length 1, but still provide fallback
        const { description } = weather[0] ?? {};

        return {
          description,
          name,
          temp,
        };
      });

      setData(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect. I don't understand how the destructuring syntax works, I'll have to watch a video on it.

Comment: @Brandon IMO it's rather simple, instead of something like `const value = obj.value` you can destructure and assign the `value` property, i.e. `const { value } = obj`. It's a bit of shorthand. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment